# Executing Julia on Apache; setting APPDATA and Home Environment Variable

Tags: apache, julia, ampps

I am trying to execute a Julia code in browser on Apache (I am using Ampps on Windows 10). I am able to execute it true command prompt or by invoking it by a python code (see the python code below). When I try to execute the Julia code directly on the browser I get the **Gateway Time-out The server didn't respond in time** message. But when I try to execute the python code that invokes the Julia code, I get more detailed info in Apache's error logs:

```
fatal: error thrown and no exception handler available.:C:/Program Files
(x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

rec_backtrace at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build
/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\stackwalk.c:84:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer:
http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

record_backtrace at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home
/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\task.c:233:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,
referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

jl_throw at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\task.c:551:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

access_env at .\\env.jl:14: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,referer:
http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

homedir at .\\path.jl:41: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer:
http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

_pkgroot at .\\pkg\\dir.jl:10 [inlined]: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,
referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

__init__ at .\\pkg\\pkg.jl:74: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,
referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

unknown function (ip: 0000000061D151DE): C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,
referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

jl_call_method_internal at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave
/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\julia_internal.h:210 [inlined]:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

jl_apply_generic at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\gf.c:1950: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

jl_apply at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\julia.h:1392 [inlined]:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,
referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

jl_module_run_initializer at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\toplevel.c:83: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

_julia_init at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\init.c:742:
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer:
http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

julia_init at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/src\\task.c:284: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

wmain at /home/Administrator/buildbot/slave/package_win6_2-x64/build/ui\\repl.c:242: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

__tmainCRTStartup at /usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-4.0.6-1/crt\\crtexe.c:329: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

mainCRTStartup at /usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-4.0.6-1/crt\\crtexe.c:212: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

BaseThreadInitThunk at C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\KERNEL32.DLL (unknown line): C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/
RtlUserThreadStart at C:\\WINDOWS\\SYSTEM32\\ntdll.dll (unknown line): C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

Base.InitError(mod=:Pkg, error=Base.KeyError(key="HOMEDRIVE")): C:/Program Files (x86)/
Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

Traceback (most recent call last):\r: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/
File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py", line 20, in
<module>\r: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer:
http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

x = subprocess.check_output(cmd)\r: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer:
http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/
File "C:\\Python27\\ArcGIS10.3\\lib\\subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output\r: 
C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)\r: C:/Program Files (x86)/
Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py, referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['C:/Users/Reza/AppData/Local/Julia-0.5.1/bin/julia.exe',
'C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/HT.jl']' returned non-zero exit status
-1073741510\r: C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/python.py,
referer: http://localhost/csvToLayer_JSAPI/
```

This seems to be a known issue related to how APPDATA env variable is set in Julia. [Here](https://thenewphalls.wordpress.com/2014/02/15/julia-and-apache/), it's suggested that that the env variables for HOMEDRIVE, HOMEPATH and APPDATA should be set in httpd.conf or httpd-vhosts.conf. I tried both editing both httpd-vhosts.conf and httpd.conf, but I still get the same error.

this is how I edited the httpd.conf:

```
#### Localhost VirtualHost ####

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
<Directory "{$path}/www">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .py .jl
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
SetEnv HOMEDRIVE "C:"
SetEnv HOMEPATH "/Users/Reza"
SetEnv APPDATA "C:/Users/Reza/AppData/Roaming"
ScriptLog logs/julia_cgi.log
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "{$path}/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"
ErrorLog "{$path}/apache/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "{$path}/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This the python code that invokes the Julia code:

```
#!"C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.3/python.exe"

import subprocess

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print "hi there! this is python!"

command="C:/Users/Reza/AppData/Local/Julia-0.5.1/bin/julia.exe"
path2script="C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/HT.jl"
cmd = [command, path2script]

x = subprocess.check_output(cmd)

print x
```

And this is the Julia code:

```
#!"C:/Users/Reza/AppData/Local/Julia-0.5.1/bin/julia.exe"
redirect_stderr(STDOUT)
println("Content-Type: text/html\n\n")
println("hi there; this is Julia!");
println("Julia is passing outputs to Python");
```

Am I setting a wroge location for the  APPDATA env variable?What folder should I use for APPDATA? In addition to "C:/Users/Reza/AppDate/Roaming", I have tried "C:/Users/Reza/AppDate/Local" and "C:/Users/Reza/AppDate/Local/Julia-0.5.1",and I get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why SetEnv does not work in httpd.conf, but I found a workaround. I set environment variables in Python:

```
#!"C:/Python27/ArcGIS10.3/python.exe"
import subprocess,os

print "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
print "hi there! this is python!"

os.environ["HOMEDRIVE"]="C:"
os.environ["HOMEPATH"]="/Users/Reza"
os.environ["APPDATA"]="C:/Users/Reza/AppData/Roaming"

command="C:/Users/Reza/AppData/Local/Julia-0.5.1/bin/julia.exe"
path2script="C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/csvToLayer_JSAPI/HT.jl"
cmd = [command, path2script]

try:
    print subprocess.check_output(cmd)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
```